# In react native conditional rendering using functional class is making app crash

Tags: javascript, react-native, conditional-statements

I have this part of code in my return:

```
<View style={styles.contentContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.voteOptions}>Votes Options below</Text>
  <RadioButtonList 
    voteOptionSelected={onVoteOption}
    data={textOptionsArray}
    value={votedValue}
    disabled={disableRadioOption}
  />
</View>
{
  voteOptionSelected.length > 0 &&
  <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
    <Button  onPress={onPressVoted} title="SUBMIT YOUR VOTE"/>
  </View>
}
<View style={styles.contentContainer}>
  <Button onPress={onChat}title="COMMENT ON THE POLL"/>
</View>
```

My RadioButtonList Component:

```
export default function RadioButtonList({
  data,
  voteOptionSelected,
  value,
  disabled,
}) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(value);
  return (
    <View>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <View key={item}>
            {disabled ? (
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <RadioButton
                  value={item}
                  disabled={disabled}
                  status={checked === item ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                />
                <Text style={{ marginTop: 8, fontSize: 10 }}> {item}</Text>
              </View>
            ) : (
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <RadioButton
                  value={item}
                  disabled={disabled}
                  status={checked === item ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                  onPress={() => {
                    setChecked(item);
                    voteOptionSelected(item);
                  }}
                />
                <Text
                  onPress={() => {
                    setChecked(item);
                    voteOptionSelected(item);
                  }}
                  style={{ marginTop: 5, fontSize: 10 }}
                >
                  {" "}
                  {item}
                </Text>
              </View>
            )}
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Whats happening is that when i dont select a radio option the "COMMENT ON THE POLL" button works, but when i select an option from the RadioButtonList Component and the voteOptionSelected variable has length greater than 1 now because a radio value has been selected, the *"SUBMIT YOUR VOTE"* button will be displayed. But when i want to click on the *"COMMENT ON THE POLL"* button the app crashes without any error, but when i press the *"SUBMIT YOUR VOTE"* this button gets cleared from the UI and the *"COMMENT ON THE POLL"* works. So its really when the *"SUBMIT YOUR VOTE"* button is rendered the app crashes on pressing the *"COMMENT ON THE POLL"* button.

```
const onVoteOption = (option) => {
  setVoteOptionSelected(option);
};

const onChat = () => {
  navigation.navigate("Poll Chat", {
    id: route.params.id,
    messageId: 0,
    question: questionText,
  });
};

const onPressVoted = () => {
  return fetch("https://soppinga.com/api/Home/SubmitVote", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      guid: route.params.id,
      userId: "1",
      value: voteOptionSelected,
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (json) {
      getData();
      setDisableRadioOption(true);
      setVoteOptionSelected("");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(
        "There has been a problem with your fetch operation: " + error.message
      );
      // ADD THIS THROW error
      throw error;
    });
};

    const [refresh, setOnRefresh] = useState(false);
    const [voteOptionSelected, setVoteOptionSelected] = useState('');
    const [disableRadioOption, setDisableRadioOption] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    
    const [descriptionText, setDescriptionText] = useState('');
    const [youtubeDataUrl, setYoutubeDataUrl] = useState('');
    const [youtubeVideoId, setYoutubeVideoId] = useState('');
    const [questionText, setQuestionText] = useState('');
    const [textOptionsArray, setTextOptions] = useState();
    const [isVoted, setIsVoted] = useState(false);
    const [votedValue, setVotedValue] = useState(false);
    const [iframeUrl, setIframeUrl] = useState("");
    const [votes, setVotes] = useState();
    const [votesCount, setVotesCount] = useState(0);
```

```
const getData = () => {

    setOnRefresh(true);
    fetch('https://soppinga.com/api/Home?guid=' + route.params.id + "&userId=" + "1", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }})
    .then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json){
        //console.log(json["poll"]);
        loadData(json); setOnRefresh(false);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
     // ADD THIS THROW error
      throw error;
    });


}


const loadData = (json) => {
    jsonVotes = json["votes"]
    jsonPoll = json["poll"][0];

    var optionsArray = JSON.parse(jsonPoll.options);

    setTextOptions(optionsArray.options);
    setDisableRadioOption(jsonPoll.value == null ? false : true);
    setVotedValue(jsonPoll.value == null ? "" : jsonPoll.value);
    setVotesCount(jsonPoll.voteCount)
    setYoutubeVideoId(jsonPoll.videoId);
    setQuestionText(jsonPoll.question);
    setDescriptionText(jsonPoll.description);

    var percentageVoteArray = new Array();
    var valueVoteArray = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i< jsonVotes.length; i++){
        percentageVoteArray.push({y: jsonVotes[i].percentage});
        valueVoteArray.push(jsonVotes[i].option);
    }
    console.log(percentageVoteArray);
    console.log(valueVoteArray);

    setVotes({
        legend: {
          enabled: false,
          textSize: 14,
          form: 'SQUARE',
          formSize: 14,
          xEntrySpace: 10,
          yEntrySpace: 5,
          formToTextSpace: 5,
          wordWrapEnabled: true,
          maxSizePercent: 0.5,
        },
        data: {
          dataSets: [
            {
              values: percentageVoteArray,
              label: 'Bar dataSet',
              config: {
                color: processColor('#F6AD5F'),
                barShadowColor: processColor('#EF8413'),
                highlightAlpha: 90,
                highlightColor: processColor('#ff3333'),
                valueTextSize: 8,
              },
            },
          ],
          config: {
            barWidth: 0.5,
          },
        },
        highlights: [{x: 3}],
        xAxis: {
          valueFormatter: valueVoteArray,
          granularityEnabled: true,
          granularity: 1,
          position: 'BOTTOM',
          drawGridLines: false,
        },
        yAxis: {
          left: {
            granularityEnabled: false,
            granularity: 100,
          },
          right: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          drawGridLines: true,
        },
      });
    console.log(jsonVotes);
    setLoading(false);
}


useEffect(() => {
    getData();
}, [navigation]);
```

This is the getData() and loadtData(json):

```
[{
"poll": [{
    "userId": "1",
    "id": 3,
    "guid": "64d1532e-8b98-4751-9101-b00aff18d0bf",
    "question": "A Question 3",
    "description": "A Description 3",
    "date": "AAAAAAAAJxE=",
    "videoId": "r2LpOUwca94",
    "options": "{\"options\":[\"Is ok\",\"Is good\",\"Is brilliant\"]}",
    "value": null,
    "voteCount": 0
    }],
"votes": []
}]
```

Can anyone spot whats going on?

Comment: I have taken other components out and tried to find what the cause is, but its to do with this RadioButtonList and the Submit Your Vote Button, when i remove these components every thing is working but its really what is happening in the conditional rendering of submit your vote button

Comment: Why does onPressVoted have a `return`? Also, response.json() does not return json, it returns the result of _parsing_ json to turn it into normal JS data. so the next function doesn't get `json` as argument, it gets `obj` or something with a similar name. That said: you don't even _use_ that data, so I'm not quite sure what your code is supposed to do. As for why things crash: you get an error, you log the error, _then you throw the error on_. Why are you throwing the error on? Who/what are you throwing it on _to_?

Comment: ill add the code for when the data is set to the state

Comment: THere are no errors in the console as the app crashes without any notification to why

Comment: Then it's time for you to start reducing your code to [mcve] form.

Comment: i have tried what you suggested "Minimal", and it seems to be to do with the Submit Your Vote button, but i guess i can take your suggestion, and start again by using the link you provided

Comment: What i didnt include in the code was this library "react-native-charts-wrapper" once removed evrything worked

Comment: looking for another graph like victory native

Comment: Sounds like if you'd run through the MCVE exercise before posting, you wouldn't have needed to post the question at all. The power of the MCVE proves itself once again =)